# Get checkbox value of own made form type in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have added the following form typo in Symfony to my form. As it is not a member of the entity I need to handle it manually in the controller. How can i get the checkbox value in my controller?

```
        ->add('showUrl', 'checkbox', array(
            'mapped' => false,
        ))
```

This is the generated html in the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cuslocation_accountreg_showUrl" name="cuslocation[accountreg][showUrl]" required="required" value="1">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$form->getData()['showUrl']
```

or

```
$form->get('showUrl')->getData()
```

or

```
$form['showUrl']->getData()
```